# Can I use same client id for Jawbone UP integration for both Android and ios app?

Tags: android, jawbone

I am developing an app in both android and ios that uses Jawbone UP Api. Can I use the same client id and secret for both ios and android platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same client id and client secret but the redirect url should be same .You can achieve this by having a common server servlet.